# How does on the fly LOD work?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

In the [Unreal Engine 5](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/blog/a-first-look-at-unreal-engine-5) tech demo, they mention, that there is no need to manually generate LOD levels for each model, because the on the fly LOD system will generate polygons from the original mesh, which are around one pixel in size.

I tried to search for "on the fly LOD", but I was not able to find anything useful.

Comment: In that demo they mention, that it is part of their new "Nanite" technology for Mesh rendering, so I doubt you will find any resources just yet. UE4 is Open Source however, and in general they publish some of their techniques, so probably you will get some info next year or the year after.

Comment: Yes, but there must be some papers about it. I don't think that they built this "Nanite" engine without any prior research.

Comment: I didn't say they did. Brian Karis mentioned on twitter (https://twitter.com/BrianKaris/status/1260590413003362305), how long it took him/them from the first thought. However from what I read online, they don't share the technique just yet. There have been a lot of discussions on how they did it, but no answer. See for example this conversation between Rune Stubbe and Paul Malin: https://twitter.com/Stubbesaurus/status/1261648521431785475